# Hex Value from Properties file : JAVA

Tags: java, string, file, properties, hex

In my Java Program, I need a byte array from a Hex String. So I do the following:

`byte[] key=HexUtils.convert("0AA387ED291F6D90");`

This converts the Hex String into a byte array as follows:

Output: `Byte Array: key:[10, -93, -121, -19, 41, 31, 109, -112]`

Now, I want to move the Hex String into the properties file. But I am not able to do so.

`Try 1:`
`Properties file ====>     key=0AA387ED291F6D90`
`Java Program    ====>     byte[] key = HexUtils.convert(prop.getProperty("key"));`

**This gives error: BAD HEXADECIMAL DIGIT**

`Try 2:`
`Properties file ====>     key=\u000A\u00A3\u0087\u00ED\u0029\u001F\u006D\u0090`
`Java Program    ====>     byte[] key = HexUtils.convert(prop.getProperty("key"));`

`Output: key:[10, -93, 63, -19, 41, 31, 109, 63]`

If you notice, 2 bytes are different than the Expected. Hex 87 and Hex 90. Both are converted to 63. Whereas I am expecting -121 and -112 respectively.

Can somebody please help me as to how do I do this conversion. I hope I am clear!

Angad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the `\uxxxx` codes, you're using UNICODE escape sequences. `\u0090` is not going to end up being interpreted as String `"90"`, it's gonna end up as a single character that corresponds to code unit 0090 in the UTF-16 encoding.

Your first approach should work. I suggest you try `System.out.println(prop.getProperty("key"));` or some other form of output and check if there's leading or trailing white space, some character you didn't expect or `null`. The latter would mean the property for "key" isn't found.

Comment: Hi G_H,
Thanks an excellent tip. The problem was indeed extra spaces in the properties file which returns wrong string Thus, the Converter gave this error.

Thanks for you prompt reply.

Comment: @tranceporter Consider accepting if this solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I had some problems with bytes because bytes are signed, but when you convert from strings, values larger than 127 caused issues because they were too big.

I think I ended up parsing the hex pairs one at a time and converting them to ints and storing them as bytes.

Also, depending on what you're doing, you might leave them as ints because bytes get converted internally to ints before doing calculations and so ints will be faster.

Comment: Yeah, if they're coming in as unicode, they're chars before they're bytes and I think that's where your problem lies.